# Selecting JSON patterns in Telegraf

Tags: json, influxdb, telegraf

I’ve just started to play with the TICK stack. I’m interested in storing values coming from several JSON strings. There are 3 types of different incoming JSON, and each of them need a different procedure to extract the data i need. I was thinking to use a Telegraf script using regex, with 3 different if statements. I read the docs about regex processor ([here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/regex)), but i’m not sure if it’s possible to do that. Basically i’m looking for a method to match the JSON with the regex, with a true/false output. Is it possible?

Edit: i'm already able to receive with telegraf a single JSON type string coming from an MQTT broker using mqtt consumer. Now i have 3 different JSON incoming strings, and i need to parse only two of the, injecting data to the influxdb database.

The 3 json strings are:

```
{"ID":123,"data":{"qx":10,"qy":0.1,"qz":0.4},"report": "success"}
{"ID":21,"timestamp":"2018/09/01 12:33:11.928380","data": "1,0,12,8576,2738,-93.80"}
{"message":"Success ID 32", "command":978, "type":"request"}
```

I have to parse only the first 2 json strings.

MQTT consumer plugin for only one json string:

```
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  name_override = "myname"
  servers = ["localhost:1883"]
  qos = 0
  connection_timeout = 30
  topics = [
    "mytopic/#",
  ]
  persistent_session = true
  client_id = "myname-telegraf"

  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = [
    "ID",
    "timestamp",
    "data"
  ]
```

Comment: That remains to be seen. Without seeing your JSON, however, how could this be answered? ;)

Comment: I want to use only the first two json: `{"ID":123,"data":{"qx":10,"qy":0.1,"qz":0.4},"report": "success"}`, `{"ID":21,"timestamp":"2018/09/01 12:33:11.928380","data": "1,0,12,8576,2738,-93.80"}`, `{"message":"Success ID 32", "command":978, "type":"request"}`

Comment: Please [put the data into your question by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57841450/edit). And based on what criteria? You need to be a bit more precise. You expect a precise answer, too, no?